# Como no obtener un ID en blanco al Parsear un .xml?

Tags: java, xml, dom

**Hola, mundo!**

Mi problema actual es que trato de obtener el id de un archivo .xml  utilizando la api DOM, usando el método `Element.getAttribute("id")` me da como resultado un campo en blanco al imprimirlo en pantalla , no tengo entendido donde falla porque conozco los nombres de cada elemento del xml y los coloco, correctamente, aunque también es mi primer contacto con el tema de trabajar con .xml desde Java.

**Codigo:**

```
        File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\prueba.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(archivo);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Elemento raiz:" + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList listaEmpleados = document.getElementsByTagName("places");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < listaEmpleados.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nodo = listaEmpleados.item(temp);
            System.out.println("Elemento:" + nodo.getNodeName());
            if (nodo.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) nodo;
                System.out.println("id: " + element.getAttribute("place_id"));

                System.out.println("Nombre: " + element.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());


              }


         }
```

**Archivo .xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<places>
  <place place_id="2039">
    <name>Tienda Super</name>
  </place>

</places>
```

**Impresión de pantalla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El fichero si existe (comprobé su ruta de la manera manual) y contiene todos los datos  presentados**

Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te imprime el id porque no esta referenciando al tag "place" sino que sigue referenciando al nodo padre "Places". Lo unico que tienes que realizar es recorrer la lista de nodos hijos del tag "Places". Te paso el ejemplo:

```
    System.out.println("Elemento raiz:" + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList listaEmpleados = document.getElementsByTagName("places");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < listaEmpleados.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nodo = listaEmpleados.item(temp);
        //se debe recorrer un nivel mas abajo(Elemento:place, que esta dentro de places)
        NodeList documentChildNodes = nodo.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0; i < documentChildNodes.getLength(); i++){
            Node n = documentChildNodes.item(i);

            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                System.out.println("Elemento:" + n.getNodeName());
                Element element = (Element) n;
                System.out.println("id: " + element.getAttribute("place_id"));

                System.out.println("Nombre: " + element.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
```

Cualquier consulta a las ordenes, 
Saludos !